# How to simplify my code add/update Document in different sub-Collection in Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My database looks like this :

```
- Data
 - Document
  - Sub-Collection A
   * Document A
   - Sub-Collection B
    * Document B
```

Here is my code :

> Something I want to add/update :

```
HashMap<String, Object> isiData = new HashMap<>();
isiData.put("message", msg);
isiData.put("time", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());
```

> Add/Update to Document A :

```
db.collection("Data")
                .document("Document")
                .collection("Sub-Collection A")
                .document("Document A")
                .set(isiData, SetOptions.merge())
                .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                    // Success update document A
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                    // Failure
                });
```

> Add/Upadate to Document B :

```
 db.collection("Data")
                .document("Document")
                .collection("Sub-Collection A")
                .document("Document A")
                .collection("Sub-Collection B")
                .document("Document B")
                .set(isiData, SetOptions.merge())
                .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                    // Success update document B
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                    // Failure
                });
```

What I want to do is:

> How do I simplify my code add/update to Document A and Document B using one-time only code?

Comment: check this out https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes

Answer (score 1):

DocumentReference's [set(Object data)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference#set(java.lang.Object)) method return a [Task](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task.html) object. That being said, you can save both write operation into Task objects and then simply pass them to Tasks's [whenAll(Task...<?> tasks)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks#whenAll(com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task%3C?%3E...)) method, like in the following lines of code:

```
Task<Void> firstTask = db.collection("Data")
            .document("Document")
            .collection("Sub-Collection A")
            .document("Document A")
            .set(isiData, SetOptions.merge())
Task<Void> secondTask = db.collection("Data")
            .document("Document")
            .collection("Sub-Collection A")
            .document("Document A")
            .collection("Sub-Collection B")
            .document("Document B")
            .set(isiData, SetOptions.merge())
Tasks.whenAll(firstTask, secondTask).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "The objects were successfully added.");
        }
    }
});
```